# Rough Metal Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I am trying to recreate the [FN P90](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FN_P90) submachine gun.
I followed a tutorial on modelling and UV unwrapping.
Now I tried adding Procedural Textures to it.

The [gun body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb5MU.jpg) is made up of a rough finished black painted metal.
[image]

For this I tried this node Setup:

[image]

[image]

But it does not work. Do I have the wrong approach? How would you go about making a painted rough finished metal?

---

Comment: Hello :). Could you please split this question into two separate posts? One for the metal body material, one for the plastic material.

Comment: Okay sorry will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Principled BSDF Shader as a basis and then add in maps for roughness and normals to achieve the look you're going for. This makes life a lot easier.
You can use this tutorial as a basis. [Blender Guru Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H5W6C_Mbck)

This is an example setup for a bumpy Plastic. Turn the Metallic slider up if you want metal.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the Tutorial, why are you using the colour trough a Normal Map Instead of the Fac through a bump? And what would you do about the clip?

Comment: Technically, you're ok to do this with a Color output, but it may not give you the results you expect to see, but if it generates an effect you think you can use it's a legal move.  Grayscale data "should" always go through a bump node.

Comment: okay, thank you. Yes the Grayscale makes sense